# ElasticSearch Capacity Requirement for productions

Tags: java, linux, elasticsearch, lucene

i am trying my best to get the most suitable configuration for my production server to deploy ElasticSearch. But after googling a lot of documents i did not figure out the exact hardware requirements for my purpose.

Below is my data volume:

Total data: 20 billions
Total Disk Space: 50,000 GB (50 TB)

Now I have initially the following Linux server Configuration:

Processor: 4 core
Ram: 16GB
Disk Space: 500GB

server: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2683 v3 @ 2.00GHz

My Questions:

1. What will be the optimal Disk Space and Shards No per node?
2. How many servers i required if i increase the diskspace vertically?
3. What will be the maximum disk space for the above configured server for that huge data to be distributed in multiple servers?
4. how many shards can i create for that huge data?
5. what should be the shard size?

Anybody's help is highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @austin. What is the velocity of you data? How many indices do you have? 20 billions can not be only one index. Is it more indexing or more query or more aggregations? Is this 50 TB all needed to be accessible all time to everyone or at some point you will start closing/retiring some indexing if you index per month or even day. There are other parameters playing role in performance like size of the document, all fields are analyzed, mapping size, etc.

Comment: i have reduce the data size to only 100gb as per our requirement . we have 5 shards we are now developing queries for search thank you for your comment.